A glitch with web interface that happens for some days
As a moderator I see post review queues, and for like a week I have a red ball on Low quality posts, it's bold - but when I open it - The queue has been cleared... Looks weird, never happened before. The browser is the latest Firefox

This is unfortunately a known issue since the rework of top bar: Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do

The funny thing is: I'm a moderator, what I can't do there? :)

Last paragraph may be the answer, already reviewed or can't review yourself: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/282094

That's unlikely: I'm the one and only moderator for a long time, and a check for that is just one if-statement in the code. But may be you're right
